# Calculating bonuses

Tags: flowchart

This is my first post on StackOverflow. I want to learn how to code, and develop software. I've enrolled in computer science at my local community college, and have a question about my 'flowchart.' My question is, does my flowchart adhere to the questions being asked? Here's the question:

**Draw a flowchart that would provide a workable solution to the following problem.**

Management would like a printed report that shows the total bonus pay awarded based on the number of years a person has worked for the company and the total bonus pay.

1. The data file is on a disk.
2. The file contains the required fields (date of hire and total annual pay) and may include fields that are not needed for this problem.
3. The bonus for those with 30 or more years of service is 10% of total annual pay.
4. The bonus for those with at least 20 years of service but less than 30 years is 6% of total annual pay.
5. The bonus for those with at least 5 years of service but less than 20 years is 3% of total annual pay.
6. An employee who has not worked for the company for at least 5 years receives a bonus of $200.

I've bounced the flowcharts I've done on reddit, but I literally have no frame of reference until I get further in the courses, so I need someone to kind of do a once-over and confirm if the flowchart works...

[image]

Comment: good luck with your class

Comment: Thank you sir! Here's my flowchart... lol https://imgur.com/a/sY3WCNs

Comment: Your flow chart looks fine, but this is not a programming related question and will probably be removed. You will probably have better luck on reddit or another StackExchange community. Good luck with your class!

Answer (score 0):

your flowchart is a good start. The things I would add are arrows showing the direction of the flow as well as a block that shows where or how you would print each bonus.

There are also some good flowchart applications like [lucidchart](https://lucidchart.com) that are easy to use.

Comment: Thanks Eric! I literally have no frame of reference for what I'm doing, so having someone take the time of day to look at something, is very much appreciated!"

Comment: no problem, remember, on stack overflow if someone answers your question you should mark it as an answer. If someone's answer doesn't answer your question you should update your original post or ask clarifying questions in your comments. Good luck!